# Javascript - copy date/time in each new row

Tags: javascript

I have a form with this filed and by ADD button I can add rows: book_date[], book_desc[], book_pages[].

```
<form method="POST" action="addpages.php" name="books" onmouseover="javascript:sum();">

    <button type="button" onClick="addRow('dataTable')">  ADD Book </button>
        <table id="dataTable" class="form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date_book[]">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_pages[]">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_pages_total">
        </table>
    </form>
```

When add a new row I want the value inside the first filed *date_book* was copyed in the new row.

I try ti use this start script, but this not work for new row.

```
var $date_book= $("#date_book[]");

$date_book.on("keydown",function(){
   setTimeout(checkValue,0); 
});

var v2 = $date_book[].val();
var checkValue = function(){
    var v1 = $field1.val();
    if (v1 != v2){
        $date_book[].val(v1);
        v2 = v1;
    }
};
```

How to copy the date values write in in the filed date_book[] in each new row?

I hope to explain my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the content of your `addRow` function? Do you use jquery? if so - add it to the list of your tags.

Comment: "#date_book[]" is an ID selector, but you seem to want to select by name. You could use `document.forms.books['date_book[]']` instead.

Comment: To add row I use a JS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with valid HTML, an input can't be a child of a table. I've just mocked–up something based on the names.

After fixing that, in POJS you can just clone the last row and add it to the table. That will also clone whatever values the form controls happen to have at the time, so if you only want to keep the first value, then do that and clear the others, e.g.

```js
function addRow(tableId) {
  var table = document.querySelector('#' + tableId);
  var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];

  // Create a new row by cloning the last one
  var newRow = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
  var inputs = newRow.querySelectorAll('input');

  // Clear all but first input
  [].forEach.call(inputs, (input, i) => {if (i) input.value = '';}); 

  // Add the row to the table
  lastRow.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

```html
<form name="books">
  <button type="button" onClick="addRow('dataTable')">  ADD Book </button>
  <table id="dataTable" class="form">
    <tr>
      <td>Date: 
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="date_book[]">
      <td>Pages:
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_pages[]">
      <td>Pages total:
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_pages_total">
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: To explain the problem I have an answered my post.